# Información Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, php7

Cordial saludo.

Me sale el siguiente error cuando intento crear un registro en mi app

Información Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near ' , 'Retiro', , , , 'asdghklñ´ñ', 'Iniciado',
> 'webmanager',current_timestamp()' at line 1 insert into novedad
> values(null, str_to_date('12/01/2021','%d/%m/%Y'), , , 'Retiro', , , ,
> 'asdghklñ´ñ', 'Iniciado',
> 'webmanager',current_timestamp(),'webmanager',current_timestamp())

la consulta la tengo en PHP7 de la siguiente manera:

```
public function set($datos=array()){
        if(intval($datos["id"])==0){
            $this->query="insert into novedad values(null, str_to_date('".$datos["fecha"]."','%d/%m/%Y'), ".$datos["id_inscripcion"].", ".$datos["id_costo"].", '".$datos["novedad"]."', ".$datos["id_sede"].", ".$datos["id_dia"].", ".$datos["id_jornada"].", '".$datos["motivo"]."', '".$datos["estado"]."', '".$_SESSION['usuario']."',current_timestamp(),'".$_SESSION['usuario']."',current_timestamp())";
        }else{
            $this->query="update novedad set fecha=str_to_date('".$datos["fecha"]."','%d/%m/%Y'), id_inscripcion=".$datos["id_inscripcion"].", id_costo=".$datos["id_costo"].", novedad='".$datos["novedad"]."', id_sede=".$datos["id_sede"].", id_dia=".$datos["id_dia"].", id_jornada=".$datos["id_jornada"].", motivo='".$datos["motivo"]."', estado='".$datos["estado"]."',   modificador='".$_SESSION['usuario']."', modificacion=current_timestamp() where id=".$datos["id"];
        }
        $this->set_query();
    }
```

Si alguien pudiese echarme una mano se los agradecería

Comment: La cantidad de información que le estás mandando en el VALUES corresponde a la cantidad total de columnas en tu tabla novedad?

Comment: De hecho mi formulario solo tiene 10 campos para llenar. Pero hay campos como el current day que se deben llenar automáticos. No sé cómo podría organizarlo

Comment: A lo que quería llegar es que cuando haces un insert sin especificar las columnas a las que les insertarás información es porque le estás mandando información para todas esas columnas. Si no coinciden entonces especifica literalmente las columnas en tu insert: INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, etc) VALUES (value1, value2, etc)